# when running tests via nose paramiko gets stuck, how does nose handle globals?

Tags: python, paramiko, nose, python-unittest

All,

We have this issue often when running nose. Whenever nose encounters global variables or imported modules import modules which import modules....(no importloop) it gets stuck in some way or shows strange behaviour. I believe the error we're encountering at the moment is similar to this strange behaviour.

running the test with unittest.main() gives no problem but when I execute the testcase with nose.run() I get a weird timeout from paramiko.

```
File "D:\test_for_nose.py", line 37, in __init__
   conf = local_config.ConfigLoader("jefne_system_conf")
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\testframework\configurator\configurator.py", line 184, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\testframework\configurator\configurator.py", line 197, in _create_dependencies
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\testframework\Engines\sshengine.py", line 137, in make_ssh_engine
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\testframework\Engines\sshengine.py", line 114, in create_ssh_session_obj_from_hostname
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.11.0-py2.7.egg\paramiko\client.py", line 342, in connect
  self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.11.0-py2.7.egg\paramiko\client.py", line 524, in _auth
  self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.11.0-py2.7.egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 1183, in auth_password
  return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.11.0-py2.7.egg\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 158, in wait_for_response
  event.wait(0.1)
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 618, in wait
  self.__cond.wait(timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 358, in wait
  _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm totally lost here, but quite sure it has to do with imports and globals is there a known problem with nose, threading, globals, multiple imports or something resembling all this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is waiting for some kind of authentication response (username/password?) from you in command prompt. Try running nosetests with `-s` to see what it wants. Nose by default hijacks stdout so you would not even see it. Looks like your test establishes ssh connection, and it fails through to username/password login. Fix it by adding your external machine to the authorized_keys or some other approved method to avoid interactive part.

Comment: thx for the answer, It doesn't show anything extra.    2 extra questions: Why does nose then have this problem and normal unittest.main() not? (unittest.main() is not asking for user input...); How can I add this machine to authorized keys... (preferably via python)